# Conditional PropertyGroup in TFSBuild.proj

Tags: .net, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying to set a PropertyGroup depending on the value of another PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Dev1'">
    <DeploymentServer>DEVSERVER</DeploymentServer>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Main'">
    <DeploymentServer>MAINSERVER</DeploymentServer>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Release'">
    <DeploymentServer>RELEASESERVER</DeploymentServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Later on I have this target

```
<Target Name="AfterEndToEndIteration" Condition="'$(DeploymentServer)'!=''">
</Target>
```

This target is not being executed because $(DeploymentServer evaluates to ''. However, if I set the property unconditionally:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DeploymentServer>SCHVMOMNET3</DeploymentServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

it works--the target gets executed.

The $(BuildDefinitionName) property is OK because I use it elsewhere as the name of a .testconfig file.

How do I get my target to execute based on a conditionally defined property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by putting the PropertyGroup inside my target:

```
<Target Name="AfterEndToEndIteration">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DeploymentServer Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Dev'">DEVSERVER</DeploymentServer>
        <DeploymentServer Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Main'">MAINSERVER</DeploymentServer>
        <DeploymentServer Condition="'$(BuildDefinitionName)'=='Release'">RELEASESERVER</DeploymentServer>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```